# How to detect checkboxes by removing noise using Python OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am trying to identify the checkboxes in the image

[image]

The top 4 are identified but the bottom 2 are not. At the same time I would like to be able to get rid of the peppering to avoid false positives as there are other docs that have checkmarks that are much smaller.  I've tried various dilation and kernel sizes but I haven't been able to successful get the box.

I've tried to dilate it and then erode it

```
kernel = np.ones((2, 2), np.uint8)
image_dilat = cv2.dilate(image, kernel, iterations=1)
kernel = np.ones((4, 4), np.uint8)
image_erosion = cv2.erode(image_dilat2, kernel, iterations=1)
```

I've tried morphing it as well

```
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
image = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
```

```
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
image = cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, , kernel, iterations=1)
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a potential approach using simple image processing:

1. **Obtain binary image.** Load the image, convert to grayscale, and Otsu's threshold.
2. **Remove small pixels of noise.** Find contours and filter out noise using contour area filtering. We effectively remove the noise by "drawing in" the contours with black.
3. **Repair checkbox walls.** From here we create a horizontal and vertical repair kernel then perform morphological close to fix any holes in the checkbox walls.
4. **Detect checkboxes.** Next find contours on the repaired image then filter for checkbox contours using shape approximation and aspect ratio filtering. The idea is that a checkbox is a square and should have roughly the same width and height.

---

Binary image with noise `->` Removed tiny noise

[image]
[image]

Repaired checkbox walls `->` Detected checkboxes

[image]
[image]

Code

```
import cv2

# Load image, convert to grayscale, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cv2.imshow('thresh before', thresh)

# Find contours and filter using contour area filtering to remove noise
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
AREA_THRESHOLD = 10
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < AREA_THRESHOLD:
        cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, 0, -1)

# Repair checkbox horizontal and vertical walls
repair_kernel1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,1))
repair = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, repair_kernel1, iterations=1)
repair_kernel2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,5))
repair = cv2.morphologyEx(repair, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, repair_kernel2, iterations=1)

# Detect checkboxes using shape approximation and aspect ratio filtering
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(repair, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2:]
for c in cnts:
    peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.05 * peri, True)
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
    aspect_ratio = w / float(h)
    if aspect_ratio > 0.9 and aspect_ratio < 1.1:
        cv2.rectangle(original, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 3)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('repair', repair)
cv2.imshow('original', original)
cv2.waitKey()
```

****Note:**** The assumption is that the checkboxes are square shaped and that there are no noise overlapping the checkboxes. Depending on the image, you may want to add another layer of contour area filtering to ensure that you don't get false positives.

Comment: Thanks for you help and quick response! Your approach is solid and I accept your answer.  Just a side question is I'm not sure how another layer of contour area filtering would remove false positives as the contours that remain after the first area filtering would be the same area size and shape.

Comment: Since we're searching on the "Repaired checkbox walls" image, right now we're only using aspect ratio filtering so if you had like a large square such as a QR code or something, it would incorrectly detect it as a checkbox. Two ways: 1) Add in shape detection with `len(approx) == 4` or 2) calculate the average area of a checkbox and make sure every one is +/- 10% of the average area. But if you know you will only have checkboxes on the image then you don't have to worry about this

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I've linked it as part of an open source issue to detect check marks as part of Optical Mark Recognition. Hoping someone applies this answer to solve the problem: https://github.com/Udayraj123/OMRChecker/issues/167